# How to find my ISP's caching server?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

I have a 2MB connection but get around 250kb/s download. I saw [a video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6I93GiIXAAY) to use Google caching, but that gives me the same speed.

I want to know which caching my ISP supports, so I can upload files to that caching sever and download files from there with fast download speed.

Comment: But why is your title [shouting at us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)?

Comment: To stop the downvoting, I edited your question before I realized that your earlier questions were edited as well. Please look at the edits people made (click [the "edited ... ago" link](https://superuser.com/posts/1161993/revisions)), and learn from that: please STOP SHOUTING, be to the point and use some punctuation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching can speed up fetching data from remote sources to your ISP, if your ISP has a caching proxy in use.  Only your ISP knows if they have this; you'll have to ask them.  Keep in mind, though, the only way that caching helps is if the cache already contains the file you are trying to fetch.

The other thing that *MAY* speed up such downloads, and this depends greatly on your ISP, is that some ISPs will allow a greater download speed for files fetched from their proxy to you.

Again, both of these questions are only answerable by your ISP, who is the best party to ask about them.

Answer (score 1):

> so i can upload files to that caching sever and download file from there with fast download speed

No. A caching proxy at your ISP doesn't make your download speed to your ISP any faster. A caching proxy at your ISP helps if the line to your ISP is so fast that the bottleneck is elsewhere (typically the link between your ISP and the next ISP towards the destination) which is almost certainly not the issue you have.

Comment: The OP gets 1/8th of the advertised download speed. If these numbers are true, then that's where a caching proxy server _could_ help, right?

Comment: @Arjan No, he's getting precisely the advertised download speed. A 2Mbps connection should max out at 244KB/s.

Comment: Wow, you're very right! I'm still being fooled by bits and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question (for which [Rubio already explained](https://superuser.com/questions/1161993/what-is-my-ips-caching-sever/1161996#1161996) we cannot answer that), but:

> so i can upload files to that caching sever

That is not how [caching proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Improving_performance) work. Instead, they sit between your computer and the internet, and try to cache resources (such as HTML, CSS, images, videos) that you and others (usually: your browsers) **download**. And such proxy will do that automatically; you cannot tell it what to cache.

Also beware that, for sharing with others that use the same ISP, proxy servers can only cache resources for which the originating web server has defined that the cache can indeed be shared (like using HTTP `Cache-Control: public` headers, without, e.g., `Vary: *`). Also, as proxy servers cannot see the contents of encrypted traffic, they cannot cache anything that is served over HTTPS.